# Need help to prove the following equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

[image]

I am able to show the equation at (2) but I am not sure how to show the equation at (3). Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: This is called the Electromagnetic wave equation. It's available in many, many places including here:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_wave_equation

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle \nabla \times \frac{dE}{dt}$ is equivalent to $\displaystyle \frac{d}{dt} \left( \nabla \times E \right)$
This can be shown by breaking down the curl. For example,
$\displaystyle \frac{d}{dx} \frac{d}{dt} E = \frac{d}{dt} \frac{d}{dx} E$ since $x$ is independent of $t$ (Newtonian speeds)

Take the curl of one of the existing equations (same concept works for E & H):
$\displaystyle \nabla \times (\nabla \times E) = \mu_0 \frac{d}{dt} \left( \nabla \times H \right)$

Now use the fact that $\displaystyle \nabla \times H = \epsilon_0 \frac{dE}{dt}$

$\displaystyle \nabla \times (\nabla \times E) = \mu_0 \frac{d}{dt} \left( \epsilon_0 \frac{dE}{dt} \right)$

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. I have solved the question :)